# Display Text using flags on user profile?

Tags: 7, entities, users, flags

I'm running a D7 site and want to use a flag to display message/text on user profiles.

I'm currently using 'Form' to capture message when user flags himself/herself but cannot find a way to display that message/text on user profile.

Is there any way to capture that message using 'Form' within flags and than display that message on user profile flag till unflagged.

Comment: Please EDIT youir question to provide some more details about that "Form" that you are using (is it some form created with the Webform module or something else?) ... Also, what do you mean with the "capture" of the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved 'Out of office' flag functionality using rules module.

- Placed an out-of-office flag on user profile and set visibility rules (panels)   to show flag only if its user's own profile
- Within flags used flagging form to capture user out-of-office message
- Added an extra field 'out-of-office' within user's profile.
- Created a rule on flagging-event to populate 'Out-office-field' with text from flagging form.
- Created a rule to delete the text from 'out-of-office' field on unflagging.